# Project Hierachy with Git

Tags: git

I'm used to using TFS where you have a collection of team projects and i like having the root mapped to a single folder (D:\Development) with subfolders for each Team Project (D:\Development\App1) and then subfolders for branches (D:\Dvelopment\App1\Trunk).

I tried doing this in Git but it looks like the commands run at the repository level which is the Root folder for all my projects, not the folder i was working on. Firstly is there are way to set up git with the way i wanted. It seems like you should have a repository for each team project. That then raises the question what's the best way to share common code between Solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless team members will always need access to every project, and possibly even if they do, you'll probably want to set up separate repositories for each project. Team members can then clone only the repositories they need. You won't need subfolders for branches, git manages the branches itself which is nice because it allows team members to do things like have their own private branches.

Finally regarding the sharing of common code, you'll want to put each unit of common code into its own repository and then embed the common code into each project that needs it using [submodules](http://progit.org/book/ch6-6.html) as sekati suggested.

Answer (score 1):

[Git SubModules](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html) maybe what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

### Solutions

To share common code across solutions you should use **submodules**. They work like repositories within repositories.

To create branches you should use **branches** and not separate, SVN-like directories. Subversion does not have concept of branches, you can only emulate it. Git has concept of branches and my advice is that you should use it.

### Resources

- More on branches: [Git Book: Basic Branching and Merging](http://book.git-scm.com/3_basic_branching_and_merging.html)
- More on submodules: [Git Book: Submodules](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html)